# Best practice to handle big entities in Doctrine / Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building an application with MySql that have 3 big entities, with about 70 ~ 100 fields each, and I'm looking for some best practices to handle this.

One entity have 11 texts, 28 integers, 17 integers (ManyToOne) and 35 strings fields. And I expect to have at least 5000 records in each entity per year.

Which is the best way to improve performance in my case? Keep all fields in the same entity, or split in two or more with a relation OneToOne?

I know that it depends in how I will work with this data, so i'm asking in a general way situation.

An article with some tricks would help a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing your schema, it would be hard to tell.

Comment: Plus it depends a great deal on how much of a performance increase you need.  Can you provide some benchmarks showing where the slow downs are occurring?

Comment: @moonwave99 I haven't created the entities yet.

Comment: @Cerad I'm searching for the best practices before actually develop. Do you thing that the best way is to try and benchmark it?

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida I mean your abstract data, what is your app about - perhaps you can compose entities with more sub-entities instead of having a huge one ^^

Comment: Best practices?  No such animal.  It is well known that premature optimization tends to be a bad thing.  Testing is generally a good thing.  But @moonwave99 has it right.  Without knowing any specific details about your app then any advice is basically just guessing.

Comment: @Cerad I'll follow your advise: "Testing is generally a good thing".